# PHP and SOAP Trouble: Formatting A Request

Tags: php, xml, api, curl, soap

I am attempting to create a SOAP envelope request in PHP with an input variable and login credentials. I am very new to this and struggling quite a bit. The web service I am using takes a vehicle's VIN as an input and sends back details regarding that specific vehicle. Enter: `1ZVHT88S375260112` and in return you will receive details about the 2007 Ford Mustang to which that VIN belongs to.

I have created a simple input bar and form to enter the VIN. This feeds into a page with the PHP Soap Request. I have omitted my login credentials (username & password/secret) but created this code based on other Stack Overflow entries. Despite studying many different PHP SOAP requests, I can't get this working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my code.

PHP

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://services.chromedata.com/Description/7b?wsdl');
$account = ['number'=>"12345", 'secret'=>"12345", 'country'=>"US",    'language'=>"en"];
$VIN = "SCFBB03B86GC01407";

$result = $client->describeVehicle([
'accountInfo' => $account,
'vin' => $VIN
]);

?>
```

Comment: PHP + SOAP is always a painful experience. Not the answer you're looking for, but I really recommend using either a library (maybe nusoap) or the PHP SoapClient  class instead of using CURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the built-in [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) class should be easier than manipulating XML and setting up a cURL request.

Start by creating a `SoapClient` object from the provided WSDL.

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://services.chromedata.com/Description/7b?wsdl');
```

You can list all the available functions.

```
$functions = $client->__getFunctions();
var_dump($functions);
```

This will show you:

> ```
> array (size=9)
>   0 => string 'VersionInfo getVersionInfo(BaseRequest $request)' (length=48)
>   1 => string 'ModelYears getModelYears(BaseRequest $request)' (length=46)
>   2 => string 'Divisions getDivisions(DivisionsRequest $request)' (length=49)
>   3 => string 'Subdivisions getSubdivisions(SubdivisionsRequest $request)' (length=58)
>   4 => string 'Models getModels(ModelsRequest $request)' (length=40)
>   5 => string 'Styles getStyles(StylesRequest $request)' (length=40)
>   6 => string 'VehicleDescription describeVehicle(VehicleDescriptionRequest $request)' (length=70)
>   7 => string 'CategoryDefinitions getCategoryDefinitions(BaseRequest $request)' (length=64)
>   8 => string 'TechnicalSpecificationDefinitions getTechnicalSpecificationDefinitions(BaseRequest $request)' (length=92)
> ```

It looks like the one you want is called `describeVehicle`. You can call it as a method on the `$client` object. It takes a `VehicleDescriptionRequest` object, but you should be able to pass the required data in an array.

```
$account = ['number'=>"", 'secret'=>"", 'country'=>"US", 'language'=>"en", 'behalfOf'=>"?"];

$description = $client->describeVehicle([
  'accountInfo' => $account,
  'vin' => $VIN
]);
```

That's as far as I can get without having an account myself. I assume your credentials should go in the 'accountInfo' section of the request as values for 'number' and 'secret'.

Comment: You're welcome. If you elaborate a bit on "unsuccessful", I may be able to help more. When I ran that code, I got a soapfault with an "Unable to authenticate account" message. Can you describe what result you got?

Comment: Worked! Just a simple formatting error on my part. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Don'tPanic I am getting 'Unable to authenticate account'. i am using node soap ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) . i want to use describeVehicle. could you please help what could be possible reason ??